# HC12, Storing data and performing OR on data

Tags: assembly

The question asks

*Write an assembly program which stores in a variable in memory the first byte of the executable 
part of the program itself (as expressed in machine language) OR’ed with 11110000(2. This program 
should give a correct result independently of where it is loaded.*

The solution to this is

```
; Prepared for Metrowerks Codewarrior v3.

    include preamble.inc    ; Do not change this line.

;******************************************************************
;* Your main program instructions must immediately follow the     *
;* label "ENTRY".  This label must not be changed.                *
;******************************************************************

; Data Declarations Follow:
      org   $0000

; Main Program :
      org   $0800       
ENTRY:
START     ldaa     START       ; A <== (M[START])    

      oraa    #%11110000  ; A <== (A) OR %11110000


; Halt execution
    swi
    nop

; Subroutine Area Follows:
    org $0A00

; Physical end of the program:
    end
```

Now my question is, I don't understand what this is doing. For example,

```
START ldaa START
```

What is this loading into accumulator a? is it loading the data START and calling the address START with the data START? Moreover, how is START loaded into accumulator a? Can you load characters on there?

Also do not understand the purpose of the OR with that. There is probably an important concept that I am supposed to pick off this, but I do not know what that is

HC12 Manual : http://www.eng.uwo.ca/electrical/e-shop/micros/HC12%20CPU12%20Reference%20Manual.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of parts in this line:

```
START ldaa START
```

The left `START` is a label.  Then comes the instruction `ldaa` and its operand, a reference to the `START` label just declared.

The `ldaa` instruction loads accumulator A with the byte found at the address specified in the operand.  In this case, that means load the first byte found after the `START` label.

The `oraa` is just doing the `OR` operation specified by the problem statement.

Comment: Also when I added another statement, START2 ldab START2, it did not load the next byte, it skipped a byte then loaded the next byte.

Comment: What do you mean "the next byte"?  That should load the first byte of the `ldab` instruction.  I'm not that familiar with the HC12, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok that's fine. Thanks alot for your answer though I understood it